# Regex to extract hashtags with two dot-separated parts

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression in order to extract some text from strings. I want to extract text from urls or normal text messages e.g.:

```
endpoint/?userId=#someuser.id
```

OR

```
Hi #someuser.name, how are you?
```

And from both I want to extract exactly `#someuser.name` from message and `#someuser.id` from url. There might be be many of those string to extract from the url and messages.

My regular expression currently looks like this:

```
(#[^\.]+?\.)([^\W]\w+\b)
```

It works fine, except one for one case and I don't know how to do it - e.g.:

Those strings SHOULD NOT be matched: `# .id`, `#.id`. There must be at least one character between `#` and `.`. One or more spaces between those characters should not be matched.

How can I do it using my current regex?

Comment: Try `String regex = "#[^.]*[^.\\s][^.]*(?:\\.\\w+)*";`. Or `String regex = "#[^.]*[^.\\s][^.]*\\.\\w+";`

Comment: Please check the second regex from above comment if you want to match `#` and 2 parts separated with `.` after it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so close! There is only one string which should not be matched but it is e.g.: # #.id The '#' character is illegal, hash only means that there is some tag to match but it may not be used as one of available special characters

Comment: So, try excluding `#` from the first group, `"#[^.#]*[^.#\\s][^#.]*\\.\\w+"`, see https://regex101.com/r/Qv8Qnl/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect! =) Now everything works correctly, Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
String regex = "#[^.#]*[^.#\\s][^#.]*\\.\\w+";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qv8Qnl/1/) and [its graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%23%5B%5E.%23%5D*%5B%5E.%23%5Cs%5D%5B%5E%23.%5D*%5C.%5Cw%2B):

[image]

**Details**

- `#` - a `#` symbol
- `[^.#]*` - zero or more chars other than `.` and `#`
- `[^.#\\s]` - any char but `.`, `#` and whitespace
- `[^#.]*` - - zero or more chars other than `.` and `#`
- `\.` - a dot
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (letters, digits or `_`).

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/W1VDQ2):

```
String s = "# #.id\nendpoint/?userId=#someuser.id\nHi #someuser.name, how are you?";
String regex = "#[^.#]*[^.#\\s][^#.]*\\.\\w+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

Output:

```
#someuser.id
#someuser.name
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regex:

```
#(\w+)\.(\w+)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y6KbAA/2/)

**Notes:**

- remove the parenthesis if you do not want to capture any group.
- in your java regex string you need to escape every `\`
- this gives `#(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)`
- if the `id` is only made of numbers you can change the second `\w` by `[0-9]`
- if the `username` include other characters than alphabet, numbers and underscore you have to change `\w` into a character class with all the authorised characters defined explicitly.

**Code sample:**

```
String input = "endpoint/?userId=#someuser.id Hi #someuser.name, how are you? # .id, #.id.";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)").matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**output:**

```
#someuser.id
#someuser.name
```

Comment: It's close but there should be possible to use spaces in value between # and . but ONLY if there are other characters. Space is illegal in "second group" from your example. So I can have those string: # someuser.id, #some user.id BUT I can't those: #.id, # .id, #someuser.i d

Comment: Also in first word between # and . should be possible to use all characters also special like ()-* etc

Comment: @Carath what about `#someuser .id` with space just before the dot

Comment: space before dot is possible but not after

Comment: @Carath can you try: `#((?: *[\w\[\]()*-]+ *)+)\.(\w+)`

Comment: It is really close but I can't use now characters like ! @ % e.g.: # some % user .id is not matched but when remove '%' then is okay.

Comment: @Carath just add them between the brackets of the regex and keep the `- ` before the closing bracket

Comment: @Carath `#((?: *[\w\[\]()*@!%&{}<>^&$-]+ *)+)\.(\w+)`

Comment: Isn't there something shorter to mark all those characters instead of adding them all?

Comment: @Carath you can write that block as `[^ #.]` it is shorter, you accept everything except space, # and . in this part

Comment: @Allan Which would also match the comma in the second test case (`#someuser.name,` instead of `#someuser.name`). All in all the requirements of the question aren't clear enough tbh.. Which characters are and aren't allowed.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen let me split it to 2 groups, first group is everything between # and dot, second group is everything between dot and ANY special character. First group: there is possible to have every special character of course instead of dots and #. There is possible to have spaces but NOT only spaces and "something" inside may not be empty so "#.id" is also not possible. Second group may not have special characters - only letters and numbers are possible here, also space is not possible in second group. If second group has special character that means there is the end of matching

Answer (score 1):

The redefined requirements are:

- We search for pattern `#A.B`
- `A` can be anything, except for only whitespaces, nor may it contain `#` or `.`
- `B` can only be regular ASCII letters or digits

Converting those requirements into a (possible) regex:

```
#[^.#]+((?<!#\\s+)\\.)[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

**Explanation:**

```python
#[^.#]+((?<!#\\s+)\\.)[A-Za-z0-9]+  # The entire capture for the Java-Matcher:
#                                   #  A literal '#' character
 [^.#]+                             #  Followed by 1 or more characters which are NOT '.' nor '#'
       (          \\.)              #  Followed by a '.' character
        (?<!     )                  #  Which is NOT preceded by (negative lookbehind):
            #                       #   A literal '#'
             \\s+                   #   With 1 or more whitespaces
                      [A-Za-z0-9]+  #  Followed by 1 or more alphanumeric characters
                                    #  (PS: \\w+ could be used here if '_' is allowed as well)
```

**Test code:**

```java
String input = "endpoint/?userId=#someuser.id Hi #someuser.name, how are you? # .id #.id %^*#@*(.H(@EH Ok, # some spaces here .but none here #$p€©ï@l.$p€©ï@l that should do it..";
System.out.println("Input: \""+ input + '"');

System.out.println("Outputs: ");
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("#[^.#]+((?<!#\\s+)\\.)[A-Za-z0-9]+")
                                                         .matcher(input);
while(matcher.find())
  System.out.println('"'+matcher.group()+'"');
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##nVBBTsMwELzzisUB1Wkaw5VC1XJAag9VkbjRtJKbmMZtYkex3VJQL/wGCYk/wE/4SHCaVCABF3zw7npnvDuzoCvqL6JlUYQJVQqGlIvHA4DMzBIegtJU27CSPILUtvCNzrmYjydA3RIGUD0AF5nR0AHERJRJLvRJ1yiWD6KOo2TKypzYP/ocvmpBU9aCWK6B5gw20nTBgRLllNfxtOn0mpj0ce@qD6NlyzZLKqiMhkxBzCyJzOxUIQWrSuco@3h6eXt@f@0l5FsOOqYaVCxNEkEkgWtC0Hm1/0ZplhJpNMmsEp0IjAalmDYECHm1MA8aqOFWjD9pI6MtVrUB1ciFNZcYzROSszm7J0OqQ7undbKKnR@Ia6o1ywUJZZrxhGHkjKfEmXgYdy8OnSBQnhsExB1f@rfUfzj1zyYecnez/n1IvQ3eKa03X8fl9LpD7riIsLuf84t0a463B89zaTLsenvDtgfbovgE)

Which outputs:

```java
Input: "endpoint/?userId=#someuser.id Hi #someuser.name, how are you? # .id #.id %^*#@*(.H(@EH Ok, # some spaces here .but none here #$p€©ï@l.$p€©ï@l that should do it.."
Outputs: 
"#someuser.id"
"#someuser.name"
"#@*(.H"
"# some spaces here .but"
```

Comment: It is really close what I want but there is matching which should be matched e.g.: #  .id. There should not be possible to in 'A' use ony spaces so #[space][space].id now is matched as correct but shouldn't be

Comment: @Carath `#[space][space].id` isn't matched in my code above.. This is prevented by the `+` after `\\s`. Are you saying `#[space][space].id` is allowed but `#[space].id` not? In that case you can remove the `+`. Or are you saying `#[tab].id` should be matched, but `#[space].id` not, in which case the `\\s` (spaces and tabs (and newlines if multi-line option is enabled, which isn't the case here)) can be replaced with ` `? I don't really understand your comment, to be honest.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: yeah without clear requirements, it's not easy to reach ***"the"*** good answer

Answer (score 0):

```
#(\w+)[.](\w+)
```

results two groups, e.g

```
endpoint/?userId=#someuser.id -> group[0]=someuser and group[1]=id
```

Comment: It is not what I want unnecesary. I want only one group and there should be possible to use spaces in value between # and . but ONLY if there are other characters. Space is illegal in "second group" from your example. So I can have those string: # someuser.id, #some user.id BUT I can't those: #.id, #    .id, #someuser.i d

Comment: can you try this (#\w+.+\w*.\w+)
you will get # someuser.id,#some user.id but not #.id,# .id